# Are there any known bugs when assigning valid HTML to innerHTML or outerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml, outerhtml

If I make an AJAX call that returns a chunk of HTML, will everything in that chunk of HTML work properly if I add it to the page by assigning it to an element's `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`?

Due to past experiences, I've always been under the impression that it's better to manually add to the DOM by using things like `document.createElement()` instead of simply assigning a blob of HTML to `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`.

I'm under the impression that nuanced bugs may arise when assigning strings of HTML to `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`. Is there any merit to this concern?

Edit: I edited my question to emphasize that I want to know if innerHTML or outerHTML has any known bugs. The duplicate doesn't cover this.

Comment: My take is if you trust the source then the fastest and most readable is likely innerHTML and template literals.